# \substack on mathematical equal sign

Tags: substack

I want to have a substack under a "=" symbol.
The obvious doesn't work. Has anybody tried that before?

```
    w =_{\substack{\epsilon \to 0}} 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
       w \underset{\epsilon \to 0}{=} 0
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it tight, use `\mathclap` from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \[
       w \underset{\mathclap{\epsilon \to 0}}{=} 0
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use the `\limits` command to make the subscript really go underneath the symbol (like the default behavior seen in `\sum` or `\prod` in `\displaystyle`); this requires the symbol to be a MathOperator though, so something like

```
$$w \mathop{=}\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{\epsilon \to 0}}} 0$$
```

or even without `\substack` (`\substack` necessary if you have multiple lines you want underneath) would work.